# How to redirect with .htaccess, strange error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to create some redirects to my site, since i changed the URL of a directory from `articles` to `articoli` but those articles are already indexed by google and so they are going 404.

What can I do to redirect?

**I try to explain this better:**

I want www.mysite.it/articles/myarticle to become www.mysite.it/articoli/myarticle

**I've put this on my htaccess file:**

Redirect 301 /articles/myarticle http://www.mysite.it/articoli/myarticle

**This should work in theory but the resulting URL is:**

http://www.mysite.it/articoli/myarticle?routestring=articles/myarticle

This bugs the URL and make it go 404

How do I fix this?

Comment: if this can help, this is vbulletin 5

Answer (score 0):

Better use a generic **catch-all** `RedirectMatch` rule and keep this **as your very first rule**:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/articles/(.*) /articoli/$1
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test this.

Comment: I did this but i still get this ?routestring=articles/myarticle

Comment: Make sure this is first rule. Also post your htaccess in question